# Unit test for C++ (Visual Studio / Arduino)

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nuget

I'm doing an Arduino project, and want to use a unit tester. What I want is to stub all Arduino specific classes. I created a Visual Studio project for VMicro (for Arduino).

However, I tried to install NUnit, but I get the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'NUnit 3.7.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.         0

I would expect NUnit would work with any C++ code but probably not. Is there something I can change within the project to make it work with C++ or can I better create a dedicated (Console?) C++ project and incorporate the C++ classes within the Arduino VMicro project?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to test your application with Google Test and Google Mock

Here's a link:
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something I can change within the project to make it work with C++

The answer is negative. According to the description of [Nunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/), this package **only support .NET 2.0+, .NET Standard 1.3 and 1.6, .NET core** platforms.

[image]

So we could not install this package to C++ project.